# Importing data securely to Heroku using PG Backups

Tags: heroku

I'm looking to import an existing Postgres production database to a new Heroku app.  Heroku recommends uploading a dump of the database to a service like S3, so that the pgbackup tool can pull down the data and import into the Heroku db: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

I would really like to NOT make a copy of my entire database available on a public S3 URL, even if it's only for a few minutes.

Does anyone know of a more secure way to transfer this data to Heroku for import?

Comment: This solution may also be relevant to some people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433414/heroku-database-restore-issue/42435490#42435490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to put the database dump on S3.

You can connect directly to your Heroku Postgres instance using the credentials in the DATABASE_URL config variable from your local machine. It's broken down as

```
postgres:<username>:<password>@<host>:5432/<databasename>
```

Using `pg_restore` to restore directly to the instance, there's a Heroku devcenter article at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export. The command will look like

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```

Where you replace `-U myuser` with `-U <username>` and `-d mydb` with `-d <databasename>`